# How to work with waveshare Capacitive Touch Keypad with arduino?

Tags: arduino

I bought  a     Capacitive Touch Keypad from webshare but I can't work with this... I  would     like to work Capacitive Touch Keypad with arduino. But I can't find any tutorial or useful information. Please help me to work with this Capacitive Touch Keypad.
[image]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The Waveshare product page has a link to their wiki, which has the schematic and example code. That board is a basic cap sense setup, and can be used with the normal Capacitive Sensor Library on the Arduino Playground.

Comment: I see that. That's not work. I try it... Thanks anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this board is designed to be used with STM MCUs. So the primary link to study is this this paper:
[AN2927 Resistor-Capacitor (RC) acquisition principle  for STM8 touch sensing applications](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/00/65/d5/81/0f/60/41/fc/CD00222886.pdf/files/CD00222886.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00222886.pdf)

After that, consider studying its [schematics](http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/9/9e/Capacitive-Touch-Keypad-Schematic.pdf). There you can find load and key (acq) signals mentioned in the paper above.

AN64846 Getting Started with CapSense (www.cypress.com/file/41076/download, sorry, don't have enough reputation points to add the link) shows different approaches of connecting shield signal. It can be either connected to ground or driven with the same (current amplified) as load signal for moisture applications.

The method is to drive load signal and measure the time needed for the key signal to follow it.

*Personally, I see no use in attached source code since the work is done elsewhere and the code is nothing more than a project setup of some STM evaluation board.*